# Son can't play Minecraft Xbox One edition without me logging in first

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've added him to my family, but every time he logs in to his account and tries to play it tells him that I (the one who bought it) needs to log in.  He is added to my family with unrestricted access, so shouldn't this just work?  It works for Forza Horizon 3 just fine (probably because it's a disc) so hopefully I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, just had to make my Xbox One my Home Xbox (see here -> http://support.xbox.com/en-CA/games/game-setup/my-home-xbox)